# How to prepare for an on-site interview for a TT position without much direct research experience

Tags: faculty-application, interview

I am rather lucky to get an on-site interview invitation for a TT position (focusing on both research and teaching) at a R1-tier university, which, however is not in my main research area. Only my B.S. degree is closely related to this position, but both my M.S. and Ph.D. degrees are not that 
relevant to it. To be honest, I have no much direct research experience and no any publications in the discipline of this position. Throughout the course of my research, I have been actively publishing and acquired some software and hardware skills that may be of general use and applied to the position.

For the time being, I start to prepare for the upcoming interview, both research and teaching talks. Given my obvious shortcomings, I want to seek some strategies and tips that help me stand out from the interview. As for research talks, I am not sure if I need to focus on my previous research that is not that relevant to the position or the envisioned research for this position. What do the searching committee really want to see from my on-campus job talks, and how can I better demonstrate myself as a good fit.

Comment: I don't understand how you reach this stage at an R1 with no domain experience. They must see something in you to generate the invite. Any idea what?

Comment: I agree. It's going to be difficult to come to an interview where you're supposed to give a talk on your research in X without knowing X for many years. How are you going to convince them that you're an excellent researcher in X? How do you plan to publish in this area to make it past tenure?